# Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla15\components\com_onlinetraining\onlinetraining.php on line 43

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Getting the following the error :

`Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla15\components\com_book\book.php on line 43`

Here is my php function :

```
function viewBook($option)  
{  
  $id = JRequest::getVar('id', 0);  
  $row =& JTable::getInstance( 'book', 'Table');  
  $row->load($id);  

  if(!$row->type)  
  {  
    JError::raiseError( 404, JText::_('Invalid ID Provided'));          
  }  
  HTML_book::viewBook($row, $option);  
}
```

Also, when i tried printing echo $row + " "; , it returned 0!!

Thanks

Comment: It would appear that `JTable::getInstance( 'book', 'Table');` is not returning an object.

Comment: could you please explain it along with solution. I am new to PHP.

Comment: `JTable::getInstance( 'book', 'Table');` is probably returning a null reference (or whatever it is called  formally in php). do a `var_dump($row); die('check');` after the assignment line to check if the $row object is being properly assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked you actually have a Table class well named?

For example, if your table class is called **BooksTableBook**, your call to JTable::getInstance should be:

```
JTable::getInstance( 'book', 'BooksTable' );
```

And if you're using a recent version of PHP, you should remove the "&" from this line (it's deprecated now):

```
$row =**&** JTable::getInstance( 'book', 'Table');
```

I hope it helped!